# How to recheck field in android-saripaar?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, saripaar

I use the [android-saripaar](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar) library.

I can check all the `EditText` fields on the correctness of the entered data using `validate()`. If I fill the `EditText` on with a mistake in correct data, the error doesn't disappear as long as I again call a `validate()`.

How can I check the validity after entering text only in a certain `EditText` and to remove a mistake from it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Saripaar's `Mode.IMMEDIATE` in combination with `TextWatcher` instances to accomplish what you are looking for.

1. Use the `@Order` annotation one every view fields that have Saripaar annotations. This is required to use immediate validation mode. If you want to validate rules in a specific order, each saripaar annotation has a `sequence` attribute. The `sequence` attribute is optional, but very helpful if you want the rules to be validated in a specific sequence.

```
    @Order(1)
    @NotEmpty(sequence = 1)
    @Email(seqence = 2)
    private EditText mEmailEditText;

    @Order(2)
    @Password
    private EditText mPasswordEditText;
```

2. Set the mode to immediate `mValidator.setMode(Mode.IMMEDIATE)`
3. Add `TextWatcher`s / appropriate listeners to your widgets.

```
    TextWatcher validationTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            mValidator.validate();
        }

        // Other methods to override ...
    }

    mEmailEditText.addTextChangedListener(validationTextWatcher);
    mPasswordEditText.addTextChangedListener(validationTextWatcher);
```

4. (Optional) There's a default `ViewValidatedAction` implementation that will automatically clear errors on `EditText` fields when it is valid. If your form uses alternate error display mechanism / widgets, you can clear them by specifying your own `ViewValidatedAction` instance.

```
    mValidator.setViewValidatedAction(new ViewValidatedAction() {

        @Override
        void onAllRulesPassed(View view) {
            // ... clear errors based on the view type
        }
    });
```

Disclosure: I'm the author of Saripaar